# Delegated with nil property in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

For some reason that I am not understanding I get this error message when running a certain page on my app:

```
Teamplayer#Plyr delegated to live_player.Plyr, but live_player is nil: #<Teamplayer id: 1, playerid: "2533033", teamid: "1", live_player_id: 253303, fteam_id: "1", created_at: "2014-05-12 13:57:49", updated_at: "2014-05-12 13:57:49">
```

On this line:

```
<%= @teamplayer.Plyr %>
```

Here is how my model for Teamplayer is set up:

```
class Teamplayer < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :live_player
belongs_to :fteam
    delegate :Plyr, to: :live_player
delegate :Team, to: :live_player
delegate :Nid, to: :live_player
delegate :name_team, to: :live_player
delegate :fanteam, to: :fteam

end
```

Here is the Liveplayer model:

```
class LivePlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :fteams, through:  :teamplayers
end
```

Here is the Fteam model since it is mentioned above:

```
class Fteam < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :teamplayers
has_many :live_players, through: :teamplayers
end
```

I am trying to get the field Plyr from live_player (which comes from the table called live_players), but it is saying that the live_player is empty. I am not sure which part of this is wrong. I am using postgresql, but I don't think that has an effect on it.

If anyone needs more information to help me with this, I will be more then happy to post it

Comment: no the id field is automated, it the field with the number I want it a different field, called Nid

Answer (score 54):

`delegate` has an `allow_nil` option that will return `nil` on a delegated method if the delegate object is not present:

```
delegate :Plyr, to: :live_player, allow_nil: true
```

This will basically let `live_player.Plyr` fail silently instead of raising the error.

As an aside, methods in Ruby are lowercase 99.99999% of the time (there are a few capitalized Kernel methods), and there's no limit on the number of characters (I would use `player` rather than `Plyr` for readability). If that's a column name on an inherited database, I would try to correct it. By convention, Rails uses lowercase database table and column names, and this might cause some strange issues later on.

**EDIT**

Without actually knowing how you need to use this, generally I would suggest using the Null Object pattern to show the missing player condition (I find it easier to reason about an object that represents nothingness rather than checking for `nil` every other line). Create a new class called `NullPlayer` that responds to the same methods that a player would, but in a way to makes it clear there is no player present:

```
class NullPlayer
  def name
    "[no player]"
  end

  # etc ...
end
```

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to default to the null object using Rails' standard delegation, so to use it, you'll need to do something like this:

```
teamplayer.Plyr || NullPlayer.new
```

Comment: ok i can understand that, but i need the plyr (or player if i change it) to show on the page. So is there anything else that could make it say that live_player is empty?

Comment: @Zach, just define the method yourself instead of using delegate if you need additional work: `def Plyr; live_player ? live_player.Plyr : NullPlayer.new; end`. Nice solution with the NullPlayer object +1